GCC vs Clang: conversion function template in hierarchy of inheritance
Consider the next code:
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = default;
    A(A&&) = default;

    virtual ~A() = default;

    template<typename T>
    operator T() {
        std::cout << "A::operator T()\n";
        return T();
    }
};

template<typename U>
struct B: A {
    virtual ~B() = default;

    template<typename T>
    operator T() {
        std::cout << "B::operator T()\n";
        return A::operator T();
    }
};

template<typename U>
struct C: B<U> {
    
    template<typename T>
    operator T() {
        std::cout << "C::operator T()\n";
        return B<U>::operator T();
    }

};

int main() {

    int i = 10;

    C<double> c;

    i = c;
    std::cout << "i = " << i << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}

Clang++ (checked v15.0 and higher) compiles and executes the code as expected (at least for me), but GCC won't https://godbolt.org/z/jxx1vrq63.
I definitely don't understand what the problem is here. As far as I can assume the discrepancy is most probably due to the fact that the class "B" is a templated one. Am I right? Are there some GCC-related "language constructions" for successful compilation?
Other question arises if one removes the conversion function template in the "B" class. GCC gives the same compilation error https://godbolt.org/z/1zqzjbhYP, while Clang++ outputs "error: no member named 'operator int' in 'B'" https://godbolt.org/z/rn9Kb4Gf4. The conversion function template is inherited from the "A" to the "B" class but is not accessible in the "C" https://godbolt.org/z/WrdK79jz3. What is wrong here?

Well, some ugly but simple and working solution is declare class "A" as templated one and its template argument with default value: https://godbolt.org/z/TMj3nr73o
